# How can I visualize post shares on Google+?

Tags: google-plus

At one point everyone was passing around a visualization tool for Google+ posts.  The tool made a graph/map of the circles that a post had been shared with.  You could click on a circle to show more detail of the other circles, but it only worked for public posts/shares.

What was this tool, and where can I find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're thinking of *Ripples*. It only works with publicly shared posts. Click the drop down arrow at the top-right of the post and select View Ripples.