# How do I view Google+ Ripples?

Tags: google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I visualize post shares on Google+?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22022/how-can-i-visualize-post-shares-on-google)

I've been reading about Google+ Ripples but the "view ripples" option doesn't appear on any of the drop downs of the posts that I've made. Does it have to be enabled somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: Perhaps the option is not displayed if the post hasn't been shared.

Comment: I have made it public/shared but I think that the problem might be because nobody else has shared it - i.e. there are no ripples to show yet. Can anyone confirm that?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your posts are public?  According to [Google Help](http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1713320), Ripples are only available for publicly shared posts:

> Google+ Ripples creates an interactive graphic of the public shares of any **public post or URL** on Google+ to show you how it has rippled through the network and help you discover new and interesting people to follow. Ripples shows you:

Answer (score 0):

My company's public posts don't have the ripples enabled either. I also think it's because they haven't been shared